# swift 2 UITableView Refresh after Almofire

Tags: swift, uitableview

I know almofire works as a thread in the background so I put in my main class

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        nc.addObserver(self, selector: "taskdataReadyFunc", name: "taskdataReady", object: nil)
```

and in my dataClass after the almofire finish:

```
init() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                let data = json.arrayValue
                self.tasks = data 

                print(self.tasks)

            }
      //  print(self.tasks)
           print(String(self.tasks.count)+"before nc")
            let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
            nc.postNotificationName("taskdataReady", object: nil)

        }
```

that leads to thet function:

```
func taskdataReadyFunc (){


        tableView.reloadData()
        print("reload mision table" + String(taskDataClass.sharedInstance.tasks.count))

    }
```

This worked fine when I start the app for the first time.
my problem is that I made a new task that adds a new task to the database and then tries to run the init of the dataClass again. at that stage, i can see the new task coming from the DB but it not make a table reload data.(if I close and open the app I see it)
how can I refresh my table view or maybe to close and open the controller from the start ?

Comment: Notifications don't automatically go to the main thread.  Try dispatching either `postNotificationName` or `reloadData` explicitly to the main thread/queue.

Comment: i tried that. the strange thing that if i print task.count in the data class i get the right number and after that i went to the nc function and pront sharedInstance.tasks.count i get the old number. its like the sharedInstance of tasks do not update. is it posible?

Comment: Send the notification when you change `self.tasks` **AND** move to the main queue.

Comment: tried didnt work. from my reading, the shared instance create ones and need to refresh after updating the data. is it right in swift 2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the sharedInstance is create only one time when you first call it.
its called singleTon.
that means that if the init() function fill the variable in the class the sharedInstance will not be update.

so, in the init class, even in the first run update the sharedInstance and not the variable.
example:

```
//self.tasks = data

taskDataClass.sharedInstance.tasks = data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `self.tasks = data`, but normal Alamofire usage combined with `NSNotification` would look like this:

```
request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    guard let json = response.result.value else { return } // handle error

    let notification = NSNotification(name: "taskDataReady", object: nil, userInfo: ["taskData" : json])
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
}
```

Then you would unwrap the JSON value from the notification. I'd actually recommend decoding the JSON into an actual type from within the Alamofire completion handler and encapsulating that within an `NSNotification`, so you don't have to do additional work in the view controller.

Comment: i did use the ns because i know the almofire works as a tread. this is not was my problem. my problem was that when i run the almofire again to get new data the sharedInstans didnt update. i post the answer ans solution in this tread :)